# Fitting model to differenced time series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, data-analysis

I have a time series on daily stock price of company(2013 data points).I took a first order difference and  the following acf and pacf plots of the differenced series were obtained. However, I am unable to come up with a suitable ARMA model. Can anyone please help me with this?[image][image]!

The above plots don't seem to converge to zero and the acf and pacf values are significant at high lags which I wonder would be appropriate to consider for orders in ARMA model.
The graph given below is that of the original series.
[image]

Comment: The data itself, how often is it captured, daily, hourly, weekly? I am asking because the charts are super-hard to read with 7-years of time in one chart. If you plot  1-year or 2-years, it might make reading the signal easier